# Socket IO - client server communication doesn't work

Tags: socket.io

I have simple project with server and client - both written in js with socketIO library. There is code of the server:

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';


const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
const port = 3000;

app.get('/help', (req, res) => {
  res.send('HELP PAGE')
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);
  console.log('user connected');

  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('Message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('message', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected');
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Socket.IO listen on: ${port}`);
});
```

And there's my client code:

```
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';

// client instance Socket.IO and connection to server
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

// listening on 'connect'
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to server!');
});
console.log("there")

// listening on 'message' (sent from server)
socket.on('message', (data) => {
  console.log(`Received message: ${data}`);
});

// sending message
const sendMessage = () => {
  const message = "message to send";
  console.log("sending");
  var res = socket.emit('message', "message");
  //console.log(res);
};

while(1>0)
{
  sendMessage();
  setInterval(() => {
    
  }, 5000);
}
```

Unfortunately server doesn't get any request. Both are runned via vs code console ( node <script_name>). Both starting properly.
Dependencies (server):

```
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "socket.io": "^4.6.1"
```

dependecies in client:

```
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1"
```

I know that version MUST BE the same, because it may cause errors.
I can visit server's help page via browser - server works properly.

Comment: Hello Tamas! First comment works ;) Thanks! I can visit localhost:3000 and I added simple /help routing :)

Comment: Hello! I've made an answer from those comments. So, is it solved by changing `app.listen` to `server.listen`, if I remember correctly?

Comment: @TamasSzoke - Thanks again! I already accepted and upvoted your answer! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if you can visit the site at `http://localhost:3000`, because in some cases the browser blocks non-secure requests, and you have to enable it manually.

You don't need the `.connect` method in the client code, simply use:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

If it still does not work, change the `app.listen` in the server to:

```
server.listen(port, () => {
```

[More information](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/)

[Chat example](https://socket.io/get-started/chat)

[Emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet/)